# calling user defined java class within cfml

Tags: java, coldfusion

How do i call a jar file provided using CFML?

I tried using createObject() method but I am confused about the path.

Is it the class path or jar file path?

Where I have to place the .jar file?

Do I need to load the .jar file on Blue Dragon server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use custom jar files you need to copy them into specific directory in ColdFusion - a classpath. It depends on the setup but usually it's located here:

```
#server.ColdFusion.ROOTDIR#\lib\
```

Then you need to restart the CF server.

Here's some guide on doing it: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/07/the_definitive.html

If you're planning on using more jar files it could be usefull to use some library like [JavaLoader](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/) - then you can load any jar withouth the need of restarting CF.

Comment: Just a note: to load the class using `createObject()` you need to know the path and class name from within the JAR. You can find this out by exploring the JAR archive using a zip program like 7Zip. You'll usually see a set of directories you need to drill down into to get to your class. This path is the path you need to use in `createObject()`.

Comment: hi, I am using BlueDragon server with .Net architecture.I dont have lib folder in that.Where to put the jar files?

Comment: Also be aware the class name may be case sensitive. ie Under ACF this works `createObject("java", "java.lang.String").init("test")` this does *not* `createObject("java", "java.lAnG.sTrInG").init("test")`

Comment: @Komal - I am not familiar with BD. Did you try `{app}\WEB-INF\lib`?

Comment: Can BD .NET call java classes?

Comment: Hm.. good question. I originally thought so, but may have been looking at the wrong documentation (BD java vs .net). Does anyone else know?

Comment: @orangepips : I am able to create the object and call the methods of inbuilt Java classes like String.

Comment: but I am not able to create Object for user defined class.It always give : failed to load class error message

Comment: @Komal: assuming you're using BD.Net, and based on your comments, it has a bridge for instantiating Java classes. You need to understand how BD.Net supplies `CLASSPATH` information to the JVM and ensure you .class/.jar is in a path that's part of it.

Comment: Yes , this is what I am unable to find out.

Comment: @Komal - Bing suggests the admin console +might+ list the classpath "bd server>vm classpath". But you would probably be better off asking on BD's own forums http://forums.newatlanta.com/index.cfm

Comment: i asked BD Forums and got the reply. It states that inbuilt java classes can be called as J# contains the inbuilt classes in .Net assemblies format so we are able to create an object of the inbuilt class but we cant do the same with user defined class as its not present in BD .Net version.

Comment: @Komal - So BD.net does *not* support custom java classes - at all? Bummer.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest http://javaloader.riaforge.org/ for loading java object. It gives lots of flexibility like you do not need to store your class file in web-inf or doesn't need to map directory.